# Jquery datatable data render function called multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I only have 4 records in my data table

[image]

But when i do console log

```
                columns:[
                        {
                            data: {},  name: 'mws_name', className: 'text-center', orderable: true, searchable: true, class:"mws_name", render: function (data,type,row) {
                                console.log(row.mws_name)
                                if(data.capabilities.length == 0){
                                   return data.mws_name
                               }else{
                                return data.mws_name +'&nbsp; &nbsp;' + `<span id="tool">&#x1F6C8;</span>`;
                               }
                            }
                        },
```

I see multiple names and duplicates
[image]

I need to remove duplicates since i have to concat some data to display. Can someone tell me what is wrong?

Comment: I suspect "what is wrong" is that you're misinterpreting the console.log and what the `render` function does and when it is called.  Can you provide a snippet with some sample data (not loaded via ajax).  See the [tag:datatables] SO [wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/datatables/info) for a sample.

Comment: what do you mean sir? okay let me try to provide some snippet

Comment: is there an alternative using `render` function @freedomn-m?

Comment: Yes i already updated the question. I discovered that render called console.log multiple times. how can i avoid it or what other methods can i use?

Comment: Why do i need to remove console log? i didnt find an way to call console log once in column function

Comment: Yes. but i dont want to call console.log multiple times since it can disrupt my data for concatination. Is there any way to call it once by using render?

Comment: Ok will edit my question

Comment: Like I asked, can you show where it's causing a problem?  *other* than multiple console.log outputs?

Comment: i have a data to concat per row. and when i concat it it will duplicate since the function is called multiple times

Comment: Probably your data table is being initialized multiple times, render() callback is only called once for every column. can check only if you share full plugin call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The column render function is *supposed* to be called multiple times - once per "type". See the [orthogonal data](https://datatables.net/manual/data/orthogonal-data) documentation for details.

If you don't want to see multiple log outputs, then use an `if` statement, for the type you are interested in.

For example:

```js
render: function ( data, type, row ) {
  if ( type === 'display' ) {
    console.log(row.mws_name);
  }
  ... // the rest of your render function logic here
}
```

The different `type` values can be used to store a `sort` value or `filter` value which is different from the `display` value.

So, for example, you may want to show your `display` value as a link by wrapping it in some HTML. But when sorting and filtering, you want DataTables to just use the raw unchanged data value, without the HTML.

Your render function may not need to do anything at all with these orthogonal values, in which case, you can ignore them, as you do in your code in the question. But you will see their effect in the background when you use a logging statement, as you noticed.

Therefore, the bottom  line is: If your code as written is not causing any problems, you don't need to worry about this issue. If you want your logging to be cleaner, then add the `if` statement.